# 'a few too many' and Quantifiers before Adverbs

Tags: adverbs, quantifiers

I have **a few too many** cloves of garlic in the tomato sauce.

**1.** I can't understand the meaning as how can something be 'a few' and 'too many' at the same time?

**2.** And, I found this sentence on a grammar site discussing how **too**, an adverb, modifies **many**, a quantifier. Then my next question is '**a few**' is also a quantifier and quantifiers modifies nouns or noun phrases but here it came before the adverb '**too**'...so is it modifying an adverb?

Comment: If the recipe calls for 12 cloves of garlic, and you use 18, that might be a few too many (slightly more than needed). If you use 50, that would probably be far too many (very much more than needed).

Comment: @Michael Harvey Thankyou, now I understand. Can U help me with the grammar part too?

Comment: "a few" is modifying "too many".

Comment: The sequence ***a few too many*** is very often used as sarcastic / ironic ***understatement***. Particularly when the implied but unstated *object* of the expression is ***alcoholic drinks***, where *He's had **a few too many*** normally means *He's had **far too much** to drink* (he's *very* drunk, not just *slightly tipsy*).

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a common usage in English.

> a few too many

which Michael Harvey has explained in comments has *a few* modifying *too many*.

We also say

> a little (bit) too much
> a little too far
> a tad too heavy

Although the last one is quite colloquial and may be British English, not sure

Comment: Okay but I have never read in any grammar book that a determiner(quantifier in these cases) can modify adverbs.

Comment: @RADS adverbs often need modifying, examples might be: very slowly, too slowly.

Comment: I am used to thinking that 'tad' was a mainly American usage that had crept into British English, but I see that Cambridge Dictionary says 'mainly UK informal', however I am fortified in my belief because I also gather that the OED lists it as "originally and chiefly N. Amer" and the first citation comes from a 1940 article in American Speech.